# Truffle stuck when deploy smart contract

Tags: truffle, consensys-truffle

I have a little problem deploying smart contract with ledger nano s as provider on ropsten. The script just remain stuck at first migration

```
Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'ropsten'
> Network id:      3
> Block gas limit: 8000029 (0x7a121d)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x1b85c85699b9f40798b5892a7492c303048915e80ac69803f94e617744769865
   ⠋ Blocks: 211          Seconds: 2829
```

> Operating System: Ubuntu 20
>
> Ethereum client: geth Version:1.9.14-stable
>
> Truffle version (truffle version): 5.1.29
>
> node version (node --version): 10.21.0
>
> npm version (npm --version): 6.14.5

I also posted on github [truffle issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3091)

Comment: I'm having the same issue was there any solution.

Comment: Having the same issue at this point, all looks the same just using Rinkeby :(